# How do I set myDatasource-ds.xml without modules.xml

Tags: jboss, datasource, jboss-eap-6

I want to set database configuration using only ds.xml. So that without using modules.xml and standalone.xml I just deploy the ds.xml in deployments for Database connection.

mydatasource-ds.xml

```
<datasources>
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/myDatasource" pool-name="myDatasource_pool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url></connection-url>
    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
    <driver>ojdbc6</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name></user-name>
        <password></password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

Comment: You have to either deploy the JDBC driver or install it as a module. Using the `*-ds.xml` will work as long as the driver can be found.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating driver module then only module.xml comes into picture. If you deploy driver jar directly into deployment directory, no need to create module.xml.

However it is recommended to create driver module and create datasource in standalone.xml because if you create datasource using ds.xml you will not be able to monitor it.